# Buffer selected messages with variable timeout

Tags: c#, system.reactive

I have a stream with letters (A-Z) and numbers (1-9). I do want to join letters that arrive within a timeout (this can change) and always emit numbers immediately. Can you suggest me which functions are best to do this?

Sample working code (not sure this is correct and/or a good solution):

```
private BehaviorSubject<TimeSpan> sTimeouts = new BehaviorSubject<TimeSpan>(0.ms());

private IObservable<string> lettersJoined(IObservable<char> ob)
{
    return Observable.Create<string>(observer =>
    {
        var letters = new List<char>();
        var lettersFlush = new SerialDisposable();

        return ob.Subscribe(c =>
        {
            if (char.IsUpper(c))
            {

                if ((await sTimeouts.FirstAsync()).Ticks > 0)
                {
                    letters.Add(c);

                    lettersFlush.Disposable =
                        VariableTimeout(sTimeouts)
                        .Subscribe(x => {
                            observer.OnNext(String.Concat(letters));
                            letters.Clear();
                        });

                }
                else
                    observer.OnNext(letters.ToString());


            }
            else if (char.IsDigit(c))
                observer.OnNext(c.ToString());
        }

    }
}


private IObservable<long> VariableTimeout(IObservable<TimeSpan> timeouts)
{
    return Observable.Create<long>(obs =>
    {
        var sd = new SerialDisposable();
        var first = DateTime.Now;

        return timeouts
            .Subscribe(timeout =>
            {
                if (timeout.Ticks == 0 || first + timeout < DateTime.Now)
                {
                    sd.Disposable = null;
                    obs.OnNext(timeout.Ticks);
                    obs.OnCompleted();
                }
                else
                {
                    timeout -= DateTime.Now - first;

                    sd.Disposable =
                        Observable
                        .Timer(timeout)
                        .Subscribe(t => {
                            obs.OnNext(t);
                            obs.OnCompleted();
                        });
                }
            });

    });
}

private void ChangeTimeout(int timeout)
{
    sTimeouts.OnNext(timeout.ms())
}


// I use the following extension method
public static class TickExtensions
{
    public static TimeSpan ms(this int ms)
    {
        return TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(ms);
    }
}
```

To modify the timeout, I can simply change the private timeout variable, but probably a Subject for it would be OK if needed/better.

**UPDATE**

```
var scheduler = new TestScheduler();

var timeout = scheduler.CreateColdObservable<int>(
    ReactiveTest.OnNext(0000.Ms(), 2000),
    ReactiveTest.OnNext(4300.Ms(), 1000));

var input = scheduler.CreateColdObservable<char>(
    ReactiveTest.OnNext(0100.Ms(), '1'),
    ReactiveTest.OnNext(1600.Ms(), '2'),
    ReactiveTest.OnNext(1900.Ms(), 'A'),
    ReactiveTest.OnNext(2100.Ms(), 'B'),
    ReactiveTest.OnNext(4500.Ms(), 'C'),
    ReactiveTest.OnNext(5100.Ms(), 'A'),
    ReactiveTest.OnNext(5500.Ms(), '5'),
    ReactiveTest.OnNext(6000.Ms(), 'B'),
    ReactiveTest.OnNext(7200.Ms(), '1'),
    ReactiveTest.OnNext(7500.Ms(), 'B'),
    ReactiveTest.OnNext(7700.Ms(), 'A'),
    ReactiveTest.OnNext(8400.Ms(), 'A'));

var expected = scheduler.CreateColdObservable<string>(
    ReactiveTest.OnNext(0100.Ms(), "1"),
    ReactiveTest.OnNext(1600.Ms(), "2"),
    ReactiveTest.OnNext(4100.Ms(), "AB"),
    ReactiveTest.OnNext(5500.Ms(), "5"),
    ReactiveTest.OnNext(7000.Ms(), "CAB"),
    ReactiveTest.OnNext(7200.Ms(), "1"),
    ReactiveTest.OnNext(9400.Ms(), "BAA"));


// if ReactiveTest.OnNext(3800.Ms(), 1000)
// then expected is ReactiveTest.OnNext(3800.Ms(), "AB")
```

**UPDATE #2**

Refined solution correctly supporting timeout change during buffering

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Several things that may help out here.

First marble diagrams are nice for helping visualize the problem, but when proving if something works or not, lets be prescriptive and unit test with `ITestableObservable<T>` instances.

Second, I am not sure what your solution should be. If I look at your marble diagrams I see some discrepancies. Here I have added a Timeline to help visualize.

```
                 111111111122222222223
Time:   123456789012345678901234567890
Input:  1---2--A-B----C--A-B-1--B-A--A
Output: 1---2----AB-------CAB-1-----BAA
```

Here I see the "AB" output published at unit 10.
Then I see the "CAB" output published at unit 19.
Further I see the "BAA" output published at unit 29.
But you suggest these should occur at constant timeouts apart.
So then I think it is maybe the gap between values that is important, but this doesn't seem to add up either. This just leads me back to my point above, please provide a unit test that could pass or fail.

Thirdly, regarding your implementation you could make it slightly better by using the `SerialDisposable` type for the `lettersFlush` type.

To help me set up the unit test I create the following block of code

```
var scheduler = new TestScheduler();
var input = scheduler.CreateColdObservable<char>(
    ReactiveTest.OnNext(0100.Ms(), '1'),
    ReactiveTest.OnNext(0500.Ms(), '2'),
    ReactiveTest.OnNext(0800.Ms(), 'A'),
    ReactiveTest.OnNext(1000.Ms(), 'B'),
    ReactiveTest.OnNext(1500.Ms(), 'C'),
    ReactiveTest.OnNext(1800.Ms(), 'A'),
    ReactiveTest.OnNext(2000.Ms(), 'B'),
    ReactiveTest.OnNext(2200.Ms(), '1'),
    ReactiveTest.OnNext(2500.Ms(), 'B'),
    ReactiveTest.OnNext(2700.Ms(), 'A'),
    ReactiveTest.OnNext(3000.Ms(), 'A'));

var expected = scheduler.CreateColdObservable<string>(
    ReactiveTest.OnNext(0100.Ms(), "1"),
    ReactiveTest.OnNext(0500.Ms(), "2"),
    ReactiveTest.OnNext(1000.Ms(), "AB"),
    ReactiveTest.OnNext(2000.Ms(), "CAB"),
    ReactiveTest.OnNext(2200.Ms(), "1"),
    ReactiveTest.OnNext(3000.Ms(), "BAA"));
```

I have taken some liberties to change some values to what I think you meant by your marble diagrams.

If I then use the very good answer provided above by @Shlomo, I can see further issues with just using fuzzy marble diagrams. As the buffer boundary would have to happen after the last value to be included occurs, these windows need to close on an off-by-one time.

```
void Main()
{
    var scheduler = new TestScheduler();
    var input = scheduler.CreateColdObservable<char>(
        ReactiveTest.OnNext(0100.Ms(), '1'),
        ReactiveTest.OnNext(0500.Ms(), '2'),
        ReactiveTest.OnNext(0800.Ms(), 'A'),
        ReactiveTest.OnNext(1000.Ms(), 'B'),
        ReactiveTest.OnNext(1500.Ms(), 'C'),
        ReactiveTest.OnNext(1800.Ms(), 'A'),
        ReactiveTest.OnNext(2000.Ms(), 'B'),
        ReactiveTest.OnNext(2200.Ms(), '1'),
        ReactiveTest.OnNext(2500.Ms(), 'B'),
        ReactiveTest.OnNext(2700.Ms(), 'A'),
        ReactiveTest.OnNext(3000.Ms(), 'A'));

    var expected = scheduler.CreateColdObservable<string>(
        ReactiveTest.OnNext(0100.Ms(), "1"),
        ReactiveTest.OnNext(0500.Ms(), "2"),
        ReactiveTest.OnNext(1000.Ms()+1, "AB"),
        ReactiveTest.OnNext(2000.Ms()+1, "CAB"),
        ReactiveTest.OnNext(2200.Ms(), "1"),
        ReactiveTest.OnNext(3000.Ms()+1, "BAA"));

    /*
                     111111111122222222223
    Time:   123456789012345678901234567890
    Input:  1---2--A-B----C--A-B-1--B-A--A
    Output: 1---2----AB-------CAB-1-----BAA 
    */

    var bufferBoundaries = //Observable.Timer(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1), scheduler);
            //Move to a hot test sequence to force the windows to close just after the values are produced
            scheduler.CreateHotObservable<Unit>(
        ReactiveTest.OnNext(1000.Ms()+1, Unit.Default),
        ReactiveTest.OnNext(2000.Ms()+1, Unit.Default),
        ReactiveTest.OnNext(3000.Ms()+1, Unit.Default),
        ReactiveTest.OnNext(4000.Ms()+1, Unit.Default));

    var publishedFinal = input
        .Publish(i => i
            .Where(c => char.IsLetter(c))
            .Buffer(bufferBoundaries)
            .Where(l => l.Any())
            .Select(lc => new string(lc.ToArray()))
            .Merge(i
                .Where(c => char.IsNumber(c))
                .Select(c => c.ToString())
            )
        );

    var observer = scheduler.CreateObserver<string>();

    publishedFinal.Subscribe(observer);
    scheduler.Start();

    //This test passes with the "+1" values hacked in.
    ReactiveAssert.AreElementsEqual(
        expected.Messages,
        observer.Messages);

}

// Define other methods and classes here
public static class TickExtensions
{
    public static long Ms(this int ms)
    {
        return TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(ms).Ticks;
    }
}
```

I suppose my point is that Rx is deterministic, therefore we can create tests that are deterministic. So while your question is a very good one, and I do believe that @Shlomo provides a solid final answer, we can do better than just fuzzy marble diagrams and using `Random` in our examples/tests.
Being precise here should help prevent silly race conditions in production, and help reader better understand these solutions.

Comment: Fair criticism. Thanks. I'm well-schooled in the dark, ancient art of Hand-Waving™, and bad-habits die hard.

Comment: Thanks Lee, very useful comments in your answer. I will analyze it ASAP, in the mean time I have enhanced my question.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming `sampleInput` as your sample Input:

```
var charStream = "12ABCAB1BAA".ToObservable();
var random = new Random();
var randomMilliTimings = Enumerable.Range(0, 12)
    .Select(i => random.Next(2000))
    .ToList();

var sampleInput = charStream
    .Zip(randomMilliTimings, (c, ts) => Tuple.Create(c, TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(ts)))
    .Select(t => Observable.Return(t.Item1).Delay(t.Item2))
    .Concat();
```

First, instead of changing a mutable variable, it would be best to instead generate some stream to represent your buffer windows:

```
Input:  1---2--A-B----C--A-B-1--B-A--A
Window: ---------*--------*---------*--
Output: 1---2----AB-------CAB-1-----BAA
```

I generated a stream of incrementing `TimeSpan`s and called it `bufferBoundaries` like so to demonstrate:

```
var bufferBoundaries = Observable.Range(1, 20)
    .Select(t => Observable.Return(t).Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(t)))
    .Concat();
```

This would look like this:

```
Seconds: 0--1--2--3--4--5--6--7--8--9--10
BB     : ---1-----2--------3-----------4-
```

... next you want to split that `sampleInput` up into separate streams for letters and numbers, and handle them accordingly:

```
var letters = sampleInput
    .Where(c => char.IsLetter(c))
    .Buffer(bufferBoundaries)
    .Where(l => l.Any())
    .Select(lc => new string(lc.ToArray()));

var numbers = sampleInput
    .Where(c => char.IsNumber(c))
    .Select(c => c.ToString());
```

Next, merge the two streams together:

```
var finalOutput = letters.Merge(numbers);
```

Lastly, it's generally not a good idea to subscribe twice to the same input (in our case, `sampleInput`) if you can help it. So in our case, we should replace `letters`, `numbers`, and `finalOutput` with the following:

```
var publishedFinal = sampleInput
    .Publish(_si => _si
        .Where(c => char.IsLetter(c))
        .Buffer(bufferBoundaries)
        .Where(l => l.Any())
        .Select(lc => new string(lc.ToArray()))
        .Merge( _si
            .Where(c => char.IsNumber(c))
            .Select(c => c.ToString())
        )
    );
```

Comment: Thanks for the interesting response, I need to analyze it in depth to understand if it is really applicable to my real case (more complex). In the meantime I enhanced the question.